Is there a way to align the periods of two processes using SCHED_DEADLINE on Linux?
I have a process that needs to interact with hardware at very tightly controlled periods. I have a second process that can start at any time and needs to interact with the first process without affecting the first process' timing. I'm using SCHED_DEADLINE to control the period on both processes. Is there a way to get the second process to align its period with the first process?
I know I can synchronize communication using semaphores. This is not what I'm talking about.
Consider the scenario:

piece of hard requires communication every 1ms (+- 10000 ns).
Process 1 is running with a period of 1ms under SCHED_DEADLINE
Process 2 starts and is also running with a period of 1ms under SCHED_DEADLINE, but is offset from process 1 by 0.5 ms.
Process 1 wakes up but must wait 0.5 ms for process 2 to be ready to communicate.

Therefore, on the first time step the 2 processes try to communicate, the timing for contacting the hardware is thrown off by 0.5ms. IF the periods of the 2 processes were synchronized then this problem would not happen.
For those interested, the hardware in this case is EtherCAT based and using a Distributed Clock (DC). The 1 time step jitter would desynchronize the DC, forcing the DC to re-synchronize. The re-sync time is about 7 seconds. I really want to avoid that time penalty since a person will be interacting with the system and regular 7s delays are unacceptable.
I have tried using semaphores to set the task scheduler up on the second process at a specifically synchronized time with the first process. This did not get the periods of the tasks synchronized close enough.

Are they both interacting with the hardware? I'd tend to expect that you'd use SCHED_DEADLINE only on the process doing the hardware interaction and let the other be scheduled around it.

Only one process directly interacts with the hardware. Assume proc 1 interacts with hardware and proc 2 does not. Proc 2 gets hardware values from proc 1, performs calculations, then send commands back to proc 1 to control the hardware. Both processes need to run at fixed periods. It is looking like proc 2 may need to schedule around proc 1.
